# Python priority_queue put list numbers

Tags: python, cython, priority-queue

is in python module like priority_queue,
but i put in list of integers and it will compare it by the max value in the list.

EXAMPLE:

```
priority_queue qu
a = [1,1,1,5]
b = [2,4,7,2]
c = [1,2,2]
qu.put(c)
qu.put(b)
qu.put(a)

qu.get() #will be b = [2,4,7,2], because max(b)=7 > max(a) > max(c)
qu.get() #will be a = [1,1,1,5], because max(a)=5 > max(c)
qu.get() #will be c = [1,2,3] 
#compare lsit by thier max value
```

I want this queue fast as possible.
If don t exist module, then maybe would be cython with c++ priority_queue
little bit change class.
It is possible ?

Comment: You can use `heapq`. Here is the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html

Comment: In heapq you can t define your own comparing function for priority_queue

Comment: I found this article about heapq that could helped you as well http://joernhees.de/blog/2010/07/19/min-heap-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

Create your own key on insertion, and insert that key paired with the list:

```
a = [1,1,1,5]
b = [2,4,7,2]
c = [1,2,2]
# Use -max as key, since queue is ordered by smallest key
qu.put((-max(c), c))
qu.put((-max(b), b))
qu.put((-max(a), a))

qu.get()[1] #will be b = [2,4,7,2], because max(b)=7 > max(a) > max(c)
qu.get()[1] #will be a = [1,1,1,5], because max(a)=5 > max(c)
qu.get()[1] #will be c = [1,2,2]
```

You could write a simple subclass of `PriorityQueue` to accomplish this keying automatically on `put` and stripping on `get` if needed. Simplest version would be:

```
class ByMaxPriorityQueue(PriorityQueue):
    # Threadsafe way to generate a simple tiebreaker value
    tiebreaker = itertools.count()

    def put(self, val, *args, **kwargs):
        super().put((-max(val), next(self.tiebreaker), val), *args, **kwargs)
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        key, tie, val = super().get(*args, **kwargs)
        return val
```

That class will behave exactly as you wanted without the need to manually create and strip key values (and it will use a tiebreaker of first to `put`, rather than the lexicographic list comparison, thanks to using `itertools.count` to generate tie breakers).

Comment: Thanks for your solution.
But it will fast enough for min. 10000 items ?

Comment: @lukaskiss: It will be as fast as can be without reimplementing stuff in a C extension, which adds all sorts of complications. Whether it's fast enough is basically a matter of testing (don't optimize before you know it's a problem). Keys are generated only on insertion, so they're never recalculated. `PriorityQueue` is implemented in terms of a `list` using the `heapq` module (which is implemented in C), so `put`s and `get`s will be amortized `O(log n)` in cost. Note: In CPython, threading doesn't typically work well for CPU bound tasks thanks to [the GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL).